# GoogleDrive API (javascript): no file download because of CORS

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

With this code, before an year about i could get the file via XMLHttpsRequest.
Now this do not more work, because of the error:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1zGxNBh-YTAXu74v855l2b_LPmLUaomqZ&export=download' from origin 'https://encrypt.pdfzorro.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

Is there a way at now, to get the file via javascript. I can not use any server solution, the file should go direct from googleDrive to the browser from the user.. without go on a server (with php e.g.) first.

```html
function downloadFileContent(fileId){          

    gapi.client.request({
        
        'path': '/drive/v2/files/' + fileId,
        'method': 'GET',            
        callback: function ( theResponseJS, theResponseTXT ) {
            
            var myToken = gapi.auth.getToken();
            var myXHR   = new XMLHttpRequest();
            myXHR.open('GET', theResponseJS.downloadUrl, true );
            myXHR.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            myXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + myToken.access_token );
            myXHR.onreadystatechange = function( theProgressEvent ) {                   
                
                if (myXHR.readyState == 4) {
    //          1=connection ok, 2=Request received, 3=running, 4=terminated

                    
                    if ( myXHR.status == 200 ) {
    //              200=OK

                        cossole.log(myXHR.response);

                    }
                }
            }
            myXHR.send();
        }
    });        
}
```

Comment: CORS may not be the real issue here. For instance, if the server returned a 404 page, it may not contain Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Can you check the http response status?

Comment: @digitalillusion, trying the request URL (https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1zGxNBh-YTAXu74v855l2b_LPmLUaomqZ&export=download) in my browser returns a 403.

Comment: Is the file public @Thomas Muhlbauer? I get a 403 when I try to doewnload it, which would indicate it's only available to authenticated users.

Comment: The file is not public. For this i use the gapi.client.request to get access of the file in the googleDrive.